# Should an SRV record have an @ symbol in its name value?

Tags: srv-records

Developer who is new to DNS/sys admin tasks.  Recently we moved a clients DNS from GoDaddy to Route 53.  When they exported the zone file I noticed that there were some strange things with some of the entries.  For example it appended the website URL to all the entries, which they did not need to have.  My question specifically is the only records they are still having an issue with is two SRV records which are entered in but not coming up on their end as being there.  I noticed in the examples I found online that the data usually has a format like this.

```
_sip._tcp.example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 5060 sipserver.example.com.
```

However on both their records I noticed there is also an `@` symbol entered in before the website URL, like this

```
_sip._tcp.@example.com. 86400 IN SRV 0 5 5060 sipserver.example.com.
```

I am wondering if the `@` got added by the file export and is breaking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @ symbol is used to signify the primary naked domain in DNS records.  Think of it as a shortcut or sort of an alias.  But not in the context of SRV records.

The naming system for SRV records is `_sip._tcp.example.com.`; an underscore `_` followed by the name of the service `sip` followed by a period `.` an underscore `_` the protocol `tcp`  another dot `.` then the name of the domain `example.com`

The @ in front of the domain name

```
_sip._tcp.@example.com.
```

is an error.

It is not uncommon to have errors introduced when data is transferred from one service to another. (don't get me started :P )

Comment: Thanks so much for answering the question.  Helped me learn  something and resolve a short-standing issue that I otherwise might not have been (or would have been guessing at when hitting save, which is less than ideal).  Thanks again.

Comment: Ill award the bounty it when it lets me